# Generate dictionary from 2 list, if value is None it must be 'key : 'None''

Tags: python

I generate a dictionary from 2 list first list is key and second is value, if value in dictionary is None I must write 'None' to the key.  Length of lists can be different.

```
def all_list(l1, l2):
    d = {}
    for k, v in zip(l1, l2):
        if v in d is None:
            d[k] = 'none'
        d[k] = v    

    return d




r1 = ['1',2,3,5,6,7]
r2 = ('andrey','kapar','isa','murat')



print all_list(r1, r2)
```

1. It prints `{'1': 'andrey', 2: 'kapar', 3: 'isa', 5: 'murat'}`
2. I want to print `{'1': 'andrey', 2: 'kapar', 3: 'isa', 5: 'murat',
   6:'None', 7: 'None'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how zip is working:

```
>>> r1 = ['1',2,3,5,6,7]
>>> r2 = ('andrey','kapar','isa','murat')
>>> zip(r1,r2)
[('1', 'andrey'), (2, 'kapar'), (3, 'isa'), (5, 'murat')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's zip will not add None's if the lengths are not compatible Your easiest option would be to make r2 a list and do the following in all_list before your for loop

```
    for i in range(len(l1), len(l2)):
        l1.append(None)
    for i in range(len(l2), len(l1)):
        l2.append(None)
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer, yes i just realized, that zip will not add None's if the lengths are not compatible

Answer (score 0):

Simple and stupid solution

```
for i in xrange(len(r1)):
    try:
        d[r1[i]] = r2[i]
    except IndexError:
        d[r1[i]] = 'None'
```